# Remove Digits After Colon Python

Tags: python

I need to remove the two digits and the colon example, 1:30 pm, but keep "pm" in the string. I've tried the following but it deletes the "pm".

```
oldtime = ("1:30 pm")
newtime = oldtime.split(":")[0]
```

The end result should be

```
1 pm
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use regular expressions. Substitute a colon followed by one or two digits with an empty strings

```
re.sub(":\d{1,2}", "", oldtime)
#'1 pm'
```

Alternatively, split by the colon and then by the space and combine the parts:

```
oldtime.split(":")[0] + " " + oldtime.split()[1]
#'1 pm'
```

The latter works only if there is a space in front of *pm/am*.